# HTML and Javascript text area word count

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, diff, match

I will appreciate any help on the following,

I have 2 text areas in HTML5

The First text area is read only and contain a specific phrase. (example: please copy this text now)

The second text area just below the 1st one where a user must copy the text in text area 1.

now I need to check if the text in the second text area matches the text in the first text area, if not return how many words didn't match

then the number of unmatched words must be entered into a mysql database, otherwise its 0 (no unmatched words)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you even attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: not really I am not that good with Javascript, so any help will be appreciated... thanks

Comment: Alright. I understand where you come from but I'm afraid that Stackoverflow is meant for actual bugs, problems or things you cannot figure out yourself and you need additional help from experts in certain areas. 

The thing you just described sounded more like a job that you needed done than an actual problem you got stuck with as a fellow developer. The latter doesn't really belong here to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am not asking for someone to do the job for me, I did all the HTML5, CSS3, PHP and SQL work and what I am able to do with JS, now thanks to Majky I have an idea what I have to do... thanks anyway.

Comment: Not at all, I was sure you weren't looking for someone to just simply deliver the finished code. But just to make sure everyone is on the same page I added what I just replied with earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried to create a generic function.

Try out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/VynRH/1/)

```
compareText = function (str1, str2, trimStr, lowerCaseStr, callback, separator) {
if (lowerCaseStr === true) {
    str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
    str2 = str2.toLowerCase();
}
var array1 = new Array();
var array2 = new Array();
var mistakes = {
    missed: [],
    wrongTyped: []
};
separator = separator || ' ';

array1 = str1.split(separator);
array2 = str2.split(separator);
var finalLength = array1.length;

if (array2.length > array1.length) finalLength = array2.length

for (var i = 0; i < finalLength; i++) {
    var val1 = array1[i];
    var val2 = array2[i];
    if (val1 !== val2) {
        if (typeof (val2) !== 'undefined') {
            mistakes.wrongTyped.push(val2)
        } else {
            mistakes.missed.push(val1)
        }
    }
}

if (typeof (callback) !== undefined) {
    callback(mistakes);
} else {
    return mistakes;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, will keep you posted with the development... cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddhartha, this is working but when I added a submit button it will not work!! I tried to post the code here without success!!!

Comment: Can you share a fiddle? That would be much helpful.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for the late reply, I have modified the code to work with what I need but still need to submit the number of mistyped words to the database , you can see the JS at  http://jsfiddle.net/Divw/22dXq/3/  cheers

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and you can check the output in console http://jsfiddle.net/22dXq/4/

Moreover you need to make a DB call to insert the result in the database.

Comment: Thanks again, I've updated the fiddle with what I have done see here, http://jsfiddle.net/22dXq/9/ the part of the Javascript starting from function handleSubmit(theform) is another JS file but I aded just to show you what I am doing, and the php file I copied the php content (sql query) in the HTML so you can see as well, now I am getting a Undefined index: totalErrors !! any idea? also note that WPMscore is variable I am using for another counter. now I need to pass a variable with the totalErrors to the DB!! thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, reading your fiddle i realized that I didn't give the input a name and that what was casing the problem, so now everything is working properly.... again many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this article is exactly what you are looking for.

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

I also found this project. There is also demo, take a look.

https://github.com/pifleo/jsdifflib

Adjust this examples as needed and you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I will update the code to count the number of misspelled words and post back. (P.S. I am not that good with Javascript so will see where I will get stuck...)